# How to run a shell command in a for loop in xonsh?

Tags: python, shell, xonsh

I would like to use `xonsh` to execute `pandoc` on all the `md` files in a directory. I *could* use `subprocess`, but that seems like the kind of thing that would be unnecessary in `xonsh`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from glob import glob
import os
for fn in glob('*.md'):
    bname, _ = os.path.splitext(fn)
    pandoc $fn > ${bname}.html
```

With this I get a `SyntaxError`:

> SyntaxError: :3:11: ('code: $fn',)
>       pandoc $fn > ${bname}.html

If I change the last line to: `pandoc $fn > $bname.html`, I get:

> pandoc: $fn: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

I assume that the problem is that inside the `for` loop is Python mode, but the `pandoc` call has to be in subprocess mode. How is this *supposed* to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want Python variables to be available to subprocesses (in the implicit xonsh sense) you can wrap them in `@()`.
Also, there's a built-in globber syntax so you could write the process as follows:

```
import os.path

for fn in g`*.md`:
    _, bname = os.path.split(fn)
    pandoc @(fn) > @('{}.html'.format(bname))
```

Note that both the `fn` and the `'{}.html'.format()` should be wrapped in `@()` because they are python variables in a subproc (because you've called a command line function to start the line).

Also, you don't need to make them environment variables unless you want them available to other programs that explicitly need envvars set.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you do `@(bname).html`?

Comment: I think the parser won't like that. Generally you want to keep non-whitespace-separate tokens in a single entity.  Note that in just-released xonsh 0.6.0 we support fstrings, so you could simplify it to `@(f'{bname}.html')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the answer, it seems that in order to activate `subprocess-mode` within a `for` loop, you can do it explicitly with an [uncaptured subprocess](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#uncaptured-subprocess-with--and-) using the `$[]` syntax:

```
from glob import glob
import os
for $fn in glob('*.md'):
    _, $bname = os.path.split($fn)
    $[pandoc $fn > $bname.html]
```

In order to get the python variables to propagate into the subprocess, it seems you need to declare them as `$varname`.

Comment: This solves my problem, but if there's a better way to do this, I'll accept a different answer.